# Adding javascript function to jMeter using jsr223

Tags: javascript, encryption, jmeter, cryptojs, jsr223

I am trying to get a javascript function work with jMeter test plan uing JSR223.
It is used to decode a string.
I have the below two functions which i need to implement in jmeter:

```
function AESEncryption(text, passphase, bytessize) {

var key = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse('ABCDEFGHIJKL1234567891234');
var iv = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse('1234567890123456');
var blocksize = bytessize / 2;
var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(text), passphase, key,
{
    keySize: bytessize,
    iv: iv,
    mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
    padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
});
var dta = String(encrypted);
return dta;}


function AESDecryption(text, key, bytessize) {
try {
    //alert(text + ":" + key + ":" + bytessize);
    var e = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(text, key, bytessize);
    //alert("Ec:" + e);
    return CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(text, key, bytessize).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
}
catch (Error) {
    return "";}}
```

Comment: try the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/35607619/2575259

Answer (score 3):

You can import external JavaScript into JSR223 Sampler using `load` directive.

1. Download latest release of crypto-js from https://github.com/brix/crypto-js/releases (I used 3.1.9) and unpack it to JMeter's "bin" folder
2. Add the next line to the beginning of your JSR223 script:

   ```
   load('crypto-js-3.1.9/crypto-js.js');
   ```
3. You should be able to access your JavaScript functions directly in the JSR223 Sampler

   [image: JSR223 JavaScript]

---

Be aware that JavaScript being interpreted via Rhino/Nashorn has serious performance drawbacks therefore if you are planning to call this funciton by many threads it makes more sense to rewrite your functions in [Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/beanshell-vs-jsr223-vs-java-jmeter-scripting-its-performance).