# Encoding a value with Javascript and providing the dependencies to jMeter

Tags: javascript, jmeter, jsr223

So i want to pass an encoded Username to the successive jMeter steps by using an encryption function provided by developer scripts.

The actual function is as below which takes the value to be encrypted (plainText) and returns an encrypted value (encrypt).

```
    function Encrypt(plainText)
 {
        var iv = "00000000000000000000000000000000";
        var salt = "00000000000000000000000000000000";
        var keySize = 128;
        var iterationCount = 10000;
        var passPhrase = "aesalgoisbestbes";
        var aesUtil = new AesUtil(keySize, iterationCount);
        var encrypt = aesUtil.encrypt(salt, iv, passPhrase, plainText);
        log.info("Encrypted Name is " + encrypt);
 }
```

Now there are 3 JAVA SCRIPT files which are dependencies for this function which I have kept in \lib\ext folder of jMeter installation and I putting the above function in JSR223 preprocessor.

[JSR223 Preprocessor implemented in jMeter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dv48.png)

Now when i run this it return me the same "encrypt" variable instead of the actual encrypted value. What is it that i am doing wrong. Do I need to provide the dependencies manually somewhere in the preprocessor?

Answer (score 0):

I got through with this by adding the external JS files with load function.

Thanks to Dmitri for his answer of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41717966/adding-javascript-function-to-jmeter-using-jsr223) question which helped me get through.

Comment: But unfortunately as he highlighted this encryption is taking ~7 secs for a single encryption. Is it possible to convert the js code to groovy/java? Do they have something similar to crypto JS or something?