# Possible to run JavaScript command before and after a jmeter step (Need to close a random popup)?

Tags: javascript, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

Possible to run JavaScript command before and after a jmeter step (Need to close a random popup)?

1. I plan to run a load test against a website which has a random popup which is currently causing my script steps to fail.
2. The JS code needs to be executed before and after each step, is this possible in jmeter?
3. Please refer to the image below:
   [image]

Comment: Based on screenshot you are using HTTP Samplers, is that right? In that case there's no "popups": HTTP sampler works on a level **below** UI. I.e. on a level of requests/responses to/from the server. So either you do not need to close a popup (if it's a UI-only thing), or closing popup needs to send some request to the server, so you need to replicate request with response, and not what client side is doing (because there's no client side javascript for HTTP samplers)

Comment: How did you conclude that the non-execution of the JS script is the reason for the script failure? And, when you say the JS needs to be executed before and after each step, r u referring to the before and after each request or page? It should be the page because JS cannot execute before and after every request. To run JS in JMeter, you can refer to this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35606717/better-way-to-execute-javascript-in-jmeter

Comment: I used BlazeMeter to record a user journey and then configured my load tests as illustrated above; the website im testing triggers random popups and from what i can see when the test fails during execution it seems to be the popup step which is causing the issue, how does blazemeter work if im only sending a http request to a url? is it not useful to therefore record and execute a user journey with a tool like Blazemeter?